# OpenRowSet query returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, format, openrowset

I want to select certain values from a table in SQL using values in a text file. My query is as follows:

```
select * from hsi.itemdata i join openrowset (
bulk 'C:\text.txt',
FORMATFILE = 'C:\format.txt'
) d on i.itemnum = d.dochandle
```

My text file contains values that are definitely in the hsi.itemdata table. Here is a screenshot of the table with my text.txt file next to it:
[hsi.itemdata table with text.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lin7J.jpg)

My format file appears to be correct:

```
10.0
1
1   SQLBIGINT   0   12  "\n"    1   DocHandle   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The only issue I could see is that the column i.itemnum is an INT data type, and when I tried to specify in my format file the column as SQLINT, I received an error saying "Bulk load data conversion error (overflow) for row 1, column 1 (DocHandle)."

The problem I am running into is that when I run the query, I get no results returned, and I can't figure out why this is. I would expect it to return rows from the hsi.itemdata table where the information matches what is in text.txt file. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: And `select * from openrowset( ...` returns what you think?

Comment: @Alex-k If I just run `select * from openrowset (
 bulk 'C:\text.txt',
 FORMATFILE = 'C:\format.txt'
 )` I get an error: "A correlation name must be specified for the bulk rowset in the from clause."